# Symfony Iterate through objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've the following object structure: `Order->RepairJobs->Parts`. `Part` has a boolean property `InStock`. What would be the most efficient way to find out whether a certain `Order` contains `RepairJobs` with `Parts` that are not in Stock? Should I iterate through every `RepairJob` and then through every `Part`, or does Symfony/Doctrine have some smart function for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add query builder:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('p')
    ->from('AppBundle:Part', 'p')
    ->where('p.InStock = false');
$parts = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Pass to render Twig template like so:

```
return $this->render('show/orders_without_stock.html.twig', array(
    'parts' => $parts,
));
```

Then in Twig iterate:

```
<h2>Orders With Parts Not in Stock</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
    </tr>

{% for part in parts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ part.getRepairJob.getOrder }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

In the above Twig, 'part' is a Part object and 'getRepairJob' is a Part method that gets the Repair Entity. This gets a RepairJob object, then 'getOrder' is the RepairJob method that gets a Order object.
I presume you've setup your Entities and the correct ORM annotations to map each of the Entities. Where both 'RepairJobs' and 'Parts' are collection of objects.

Hopefully this makes sense. But this is how it is done, and it makes things extremely easy to code.